# My ASP.NET Core application doesn't work on EC2 (Windows 2022)

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-ec2

```
"AccountServer": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "api/account",
      "applicationUrl": "https://52.79.136.53:8888;http://52.79.136.53:8889",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
}
```

This is the `launchSettings.json` of my application.

`applicationUrl` is my private IPv4 address of EC2.

But on EC2, it show listening on localhost:

[image: Working in EC2]

What is this problem? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `launchSettings.json` is basically used by IDE (Visual Studio 2022 or other version), not really by the runtime itself.

When you double click the `.exe` file or use `dotnet <project_name>.dll` command, it will use the default port 5000.

And you also can use command below to start the application.

```
--urls=https://localhost:5002
```

[image]